# Hyper V External Switch MAC Address Spoofing

Tags: virtual-machines, mac-address, hyper-v-server-2016

I am trying to replace a layer 2 VPN physical server with a Hyper V virtual machine, but it doesn't look like packets are making it out of the virtual server. Does Hyper V stop spoofed MAC address packets on an 'external' switch even if the checkbox to allow spoofed packets is checked?